# How does one remove items from the menu plugin on LXPanel?

Tags: lxde

How does one remove items from the menu plugin on the panel?

I am using lubuntu 11.10, LXPanel 0.5.8.

Answer (score 3):

In the file `.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels/panel` you can find the following stanza:

```
Plugin {
    type = menu
    Config {
        image=/usr/share/lxde/images/lxde-icon.png
        system {
        }
        separator {
        }
        item {
            command=run
        }
        separator {
        }
        item {
            image=gnome-logout
            command=logout
        }
    }
}
```

The most of the menu is constructed from the content of the directory `/usr/share/applications/`, where applications put their *desktop* files, and in the menu is organized based on the content of the *Categories* field.

Comment: This is not true. You can delete every file in /usr/share/applications and /usr/share/desktop-directories (and any other .desktop and .directory file you can find) run xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate, run lxpanelctl restart , log out, log in and the menu is STILL THERE. It is immutable.